# Making a png image transparent

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

If I want to make a .png image transparent, I CAN'T

```
blue = Image.open(image_path + "blue_color.png")
blue.putalpha(100)
```

But if I do this

```
blue = blue.convert('RGBA')
```

Now i can make it transparent.

I just want to know what am I doing with this code

```
.convert('RGBA')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HliE1.png)

Comment: Why can't you run your first 2 lines of code? What happens? They should work fine.

Comment: You've gone very quiet. How did you get on with the suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

```
blue = blue.convert('RGBA')
```

The **convert** method in the Python Imaging Library (PIL) , Pillow, is used to change the image mode. In the case of PNG images, sometimes the mode might not be set to 'RGBA' (Red, Green, Blue, Alpha), which includes an alpha channel for transparency.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason you cannot do what you are trying to do. There are multiple ways you can go from an RGB image to an RGBA image. I'll show two methods, separated by a horizontal rule.

---

```
from PIL import Image

# Create 64x64 RGB image in blue
RGB = Image.new('RGB', (64,64), 'blue')

# Convert mode to RGBA
RGBA = RGB.convert('RGBA')

print(RGBA)
```

**Output**:

The image is now RGBA:

```
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=64x64>
```

---

```
from PIL import Image

# Create 64x64 RGB image in blue
im = Image.new('RGB', (64,64), 'blue')

# Push in an alpha channel, forcing mode change from RGB to RGBA
im.putalpha(32)

print(im)
```

**Output:**

Image has been forced from RGB to RGBA:

```
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=64x64>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
blue.putalpha(100)
```

putalpha is from 0 to 255 and its define transparency of background
but at the first u have to introduce your image as a png so u have to say to compiler my image is RGBA which is has an Alpha (RED,GREEN,BLUE,ALPHA(transparency))